# Get all rollover indexes in ES

Tags: elasticsearch, rollover, elasticsearch-6

I have elastic search rollover indexes like as shown below

```
/logs-dev-myapp-000001
/logs-dev-myapp-000002
/logs-dev-myapp-000003
/logs-dev-myapp-000004
/logs-dev-myapp-000005
:
:
/logs-dev-myapp-000030
```

Can anyone please tell me how to find all the rollover indexes from a ES GET query. Also is there any way in which we can find the oldest and newest index rollover indexes in Elastic Search

I am using ElasticSearch-6.4 Version

Answer (score 2):

### List of Indexes

To know the list of indexes using its prefix, you can make use of below URL

`http://<your_host_name>:<your_port_num>/_cat/indices/logs-dev-myapp-*?v&s=i`

or use below GET query

```
GET /_cat/indices/logs-dev-myapp-*?v&s=i
```

### Highest and Lowest (based on document counts)

Now for the highest and lowest, I suppose when you mean it you are asking with respect to documents count, you can make use of the below aggregation query.

*Note that the below query would also display list of indexes.*

```
POST logs-dev-myapp-*/_search
{  
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{  
      "indices":{  
         "terms":{  
            "field":"_index",
            "size":100
         }
      },
      "max":{  
         "max_bucket":{  
            "buckets_path":"indices._count"
         }
      },
      "min":{  
         "min_bucket":{  
            "buckets_path":"indices._count"
         }
      }
   },
   "sort":[  
      {  
         "_index":{  
            "order":"asc"
         }
      }
   ],
   "script_fields":{  
      "index_name":{  
         "script":{  
            "lang":"painless",
            "source":"doc['_index']"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

### Useful Links

Refer to this [LINK](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index-field.html) for more info in the field `_index`.

And I've made use of [Max Bucket](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-max-bucket-aggregation.html) and [Min Bucket](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-min-bucket-aggregation.html) pipeline aggregations with [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm a newbie in ElasticSearch. If possible can you please explain me few things like why it is given `"size":0`, use of that `script_fields`, reason for `size":100` in `indices`, also how the min and max is calculated whether it is from size of the indexes etc

Comment: `"size": 0` so that you only see aggregation results. Or else it would also show you the documents for that indexes too. `"size": 100` so that your aggregation result displays all the indexes(seeing that you have 30 as mentioned in the query). Min/Max is calculated not from `size` but from `document count`. Seeing that its log data and same format of documents would be in all indexes, considering `document counts` should suffice.

Comment: Also correcting my question regarding highest and the lowest rollover indexes. Actually what I mean by lowest is the oldest index and highest is the latest index

Comment: `script_fields` would come in place if you change the `"size":0` to something else. In that case your query result (not aggregration result) would only show the index name instead of returning entire document with all the fields. It is meant to return specific fields in the search query response (not aggregation part). You can change the `size` to `1`, try once with `script fields` and again by removing script fields, you'll be able to see the difference. You can remove it for your use case. Sorry I've mentioned it unnecessarily.

Comment: @AlexMan Sure, I will see what I can do. In the meantime could you update in the question specifying that you are looking for oldest and newest index. If not me, someone else can quickly help.